# No values retrieved for User Manager.Id and Manger.Manager.Id in loop?

Tags: apex, soql

I am using below code to display the User's Manager but unable to get the values for the Manager's Manager.

```
List<User> uslist = [select ID,ManagerID,Manager.ManagerId,Manager.Manager.ManagerID from user limit 100];

for(user u : uslist)
{

    if(u.Manager.ManagerID <> null)
    {
        system.debug(u.Manager.ManagerID); //It works fine

        if(u.Manager.Manager.MangerID <> null)
        {
            system.debug(u.Manager.Manager.MangerID); //struck here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is managerId field of your user populated?? Does your user have manger?

Comment: Yes. i have 5 levels of managers.

Comment: oh...Awesome. I got record which are not having managerID..Thank you..

Comment: Now its working..

Comment: I got one more question .. how to check the values are not present ? where again same error came.

Comment: I can add the null check.  You saved a lot.

Comment: Got error again.

Comment: add null check to ur soql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be 

`system.debug(u.Manager.MangerID);`

?

### Update

In your select statment `Manager.Manager.Manager.ManagerID` needs to read `Manager.Manager.ManagerID` (same # of levels as debug)

Comment: tried : got the message "Invalid field MangerID for SObject User  "

Comment: but the first System debug works?

Comment: List<User> uslist = [select ID,ManagerID,Manager.ManagerId,Manager.Manager.Manager.ManagerID from user limit 100];
for(user u : uslist)
{
    
    if(u.Manager.ManagerID <> null)
    {
        system.debug(u.Manager.ManagerID); //It works fine
     
        if(u.Manager.Manager.MangerID <> null)
        {
            system.debug(u.Manager.Manager.MangerID); //struck here
        }
    }
}

Comment: @bharath `Manager.Manager.Manager.Manag‌​erID` needs to be `Manager.Manager.Manag‌​erID` in your select statement

Comment: Updated but still having the invalid field for user object.

Comment: @bharath you mis-spelled `ManagerId` with `MangerID` in two places